# What wrong with this overload of the operator+?

Tags: c++, reference, operator-overloading

I have a class called List which implements a linked list.

I'm trying to overload the '+' operator of a linked list class so I can do this kind of thing:

```
List l1;
/* add a and b to l1 */
List l2;
/* add c and d to l2 */
List l3 = l1 + l2;
/* l3 contains a, b, c, d and l1 and l2 are unchanged */
```

I've implemented operator+= like so, and it appears to work fine.

```
List& List::operator+=(List& otherList) {
  Node* currNode = otherList.getHead();
  while (currNode) {
    this->add(currNode->getData());
    currNode = currNode->getNext();
  }
  return *this;
}
```

Here's my attempt at implementing operator+ but it doesn't appear to work.

```
List List::operator+(List& otherList) {
  List* l = new List();
  l += *this;
  l += otherList;
  return *l;
}
```

When I try it like so:

```
List l1;
List l2;
List l3;
l3 = l1 + l2;
```

I get this error:

```
Main.cc:25:13: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘l3 = List::operator+(List&)((* & l2))’
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE: I also have an operator= that looks like this and appears to work fine

```
List& List::operator=(List& otherList);
```

Comment: Have you a copy-assignment operator?

Comment: Sir, step away from this code and rest for a couple hours ;)

Comment: Also, your implementation of `operator+` can be improved drastically. Particularly, the replacement of dynamically-allocated memory with stack-based objects.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Does "copy-assignment operator" mean operator=?  If so, yes I have a "List& List::operator=(List& otherList);" implemented and working.  Thanks!

Comment: @MartinJ. Not bad advice, but I'd like to get this working now -- anything specific that you think is silly that I'm missing?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Thanks but can you elaborate?  I thought the operator+ needed to return a new dynamically allocated List as the two lists being added together needed to remain untouched.

Comment: Yes, `operator+()` must not mutate the two objects. But in order to do that the correct way would be to create a *copy* of the object, not necessarily dynamically-allocated memory. For this, you would do `List l(*this); l += otherList; return l;`. Note that that code will only work if your `List` class has a working copy-constructor. If it compiles as normal, then you have one - if not, then you need to implement one.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Thanks for the help.  It looks like I have a working solution (albeit using dynamically allocated mem).  I've posted by answer here.

Comment: @RobertHume: My joke was referring to what the first comment pointed out (and also what the most-voted answer is saying): the error you're getting is about `operator=`, not `operator+`. This looks like a trivial mistake to me, the kind I make when I have just been working too long on the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

Your `operator+` is not at fault; you are apparently missing a copy assignment operator.

Also, stop dynamically allocating everything; you're leaking like a seive.

Answer (score 1):

If `operator+=` is correct then just do this (outside of your class definition):

```
List operator+(List x, List const &y) { return x += y; }
```

As others have said, since you are copying your objects, you **must** have a copy-assignment operator, and a copy-constructor and a destructor.  (Unless the default ones work, which we can't be sure about without seeing the definition of `List`).

Comment: But if I do `return x += y`, am I not changing the contents of 'x'?  My understanding is (like, `int x = y + z;` which returns a new int `x` without altering `y` or `z`) the operator+ must create a new List that contains the elements of both x and y.  Am I correct in this?

Comment: No, you're creating a local variable and modifying that, then returning it. The parameter `List x` means that `x` is a copy of the argument passed in.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found a solution that will suffice ... this worked for me:

```
List& List::operator+(List& otherList) {
  List* l = new List();
  *l += *this;
  *l += otherList;
  return *l;
}
```

Thanks for the help, everyone.

Comment: `operator+()` actually shouldn't return a reference. How does this help you exactly?